# Understanding fireplace junction box outlets

Tags: wiring, fireplace

I want to setup [my gas fireplace](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/820874/Heatilator-Nd3630.html) for home automation, roughly following a guide like [this](http://thedataist.com/off-topic-how-to-automate-your-gas-fireplace/) or [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/homeautomation/comments/3tpxm5/zwave_fireplace_install/).

I'm planning to use [GoControl Z-Wave Isolated Contact Fixture Module - FS20Z-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ER6MH22) or the [FortrezZ
MIMOlite](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B6RZ7MM).

I need to get power to the Z-Wave Relay. Under my fireplace is a junction box with 3 outlets: TRANS, REM/AUX, and FAN. Just like the one shown below.

Does it matter which of these 3 outlets I plug into? I cannot figure out what the difference between them are, even after looking at the fireplace manual. Are these simple 120V outlets that are always on?

Trying to understand why each is labeled differently and what that means for me.

[image: fireplace junction box]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just a [junction box cover with receptacles that are labeled for fireplace units](http://www.stove-parts-unlimited.com/Quadrafire-Heatilator-Heat-N-Glo-Junction-Box-p/4021-013.htm). Indeed they **are** "simple 120V outlets that are always on" as can be seen in this picture of the backside of the box:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I saw that back but didn't know what was happening in the encased area. So the labels serve basically no purpose whatsoever? It's also confusing due to the Hot & Neutral 1-5 spots being there.

Comment: Those are recessed spade terminals for additional power connections/wires utilized by various gas fireplace manufacturers. I don't like it at all as a curious kid could very easily probe those terminals and get shocked. I guess one could argue the same about any receptacle but you have 5 open holes with hot spade terminals in there and it would make me nervous if it was in an easily accessible location. If you don't need them, at least cover up those holes with duct/gaffer's tape or something.

Comment: I believe the FAN outlet HOT is brought out to a spade (notice the extra spade by the FAN outlet on the HOT side).  If you want that outlet to be always-on you jumper that to the adjacent HOT spade.  My gas fireplace still has that jumper ziptied to the wiring in case you want to use it.  Some remotes will put a relay across those terminals to control the FAN outlet.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is super old, but here is another pic inside that box. There is literally nothing special in there.
[image: behind the panel on a fireplace junction box]

Comment: Looking closely at the picture seems to confirm the comment above by @BenJackson: a jumper is required on the hot side to activate FAN outlet.